# HTML CSS image size

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble sizing an image with CSS.

That's because I set it as 50% but after i need to use it as 100%.

Here is the problem [link](http://paula.url.ph/temvaga)

When I click "compare" on the top, the size of the image doesn't fill the box.

Any ideas?

Comment: please post your code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.compare-basket .product__image {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Add the above CSS

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.
edit your css file `http://paula.url.ph/temvaga/css/component.css`
and add this code in that file.

```
.compare-basket img{
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}
```